# Updating records in sql

Tags: sql

I need to update certain records in my table. Basically I need to update records whose created date is from 17/11/2015 onwards. So do I update them by filtering it on created date of is it best use between clause and choose Id fields. Please advice

Comment: First option with index on createddate column

Comment: Tag dbms product used. Add table definition, sample table data and expected output.

Answer (score 2):

Using standard SQL, it would be

```
UPDATE my_table
  SET a_column = "new value"
  WHERE created_date >= DATE '2015-11-17';
```

An index on `created_date` would be helpful to performance, but not required.